# KStream-GlobalKTable-Join using Spring-Cloud-Stream - How to check the content of the GlobalKTable?

Tags: join, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm implementing a KStream-GlobalKTable-Join using Spring-Cloud-Stream and I'm facing the problem, that the join operation doesn't get any matches, but it definitely should. The code looks as follows:

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(CustomProcessor.class)
public class MyProcessor {
  private static final Log LOGGER = 
  LogFactory.getLog(MyProcessor.class);

  @Autowired
  private InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;

  ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Object, Object> keyValueStore;

  @StreamListener
  @SendTo(CustomProcessor.OUTPUT)
  public KStream<EventKey, EventEnriched> process(
    @Input(CustomProcessor.INPUT) KStream<EventKey, EventEnriched> inputStream,
    @Input(CustomProcessor.LOOKUP) GlobalKTable<LookupKey, LookupData> lookupStore
  ) {

    keyValueStore = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore("lookupStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

    LOGGER.info("Lookup: " + keyValueStore.get(new LookupKey("google.de")));

    return inputStream.leftJoin(
      lookupStore,
      (inputKey, inputValue) -> {
        return new LookupKey(inputValue.getDomain().replace("www.", ""));
      },
      this::enrichData
    );
  }


  public EventEnriched enrichData(EventEnriched input, LookupData lookupRecord) {

    ...

  }
}
```

Here the **CustomProcessor**:

```
public interface CustomProcessor extends KafkaStreamsProcessor {
  String INPUT = "input";
  String OUTPUT = "output";
  String LOOKUP = "lookupTable";

  @Input(CustomProcessor.LOOKUP)
  GlobalKTable<LookupKey, ?> lookupTable();
}
```

Without calling the line in **MyProcessor**

```
keyValueStore.get(...)
```

the code runs fine, but the GlobalKTable seems to be null. But if I call

```
LOGGER.info("Lookup: " + keyValueStore.get(new LookupKey("google.de")));
```

in order to inpect the GlobalKTable, runnig the application fails with:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-26T09:04:00.000 [ERROR] [main-858] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] [reportFailure:858] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Cannot setup StreamListener for public org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream MyProcessor.process(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.GlobalKTable); nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:214)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.doPostProcess(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:226)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.injectAndPostProcessDependencies(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at Transformer.main(Transformer.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:179)
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at MyProcessor.process(MyProcessor.java:62)
... 20 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anybody see a problem in the code? How can I inspect the content of the GlobaKTable?

Best regards
Martin

Comment: I think that the keys of type LookupKey could be the reason, whe join doesn't get any matches. Maybe there is a problem with the equality of the left-key and right-key objects.

Comment: How are you materializing that "lookupStore". I am not seeing anywhere that you are materializing any data to the store. It could be that the state store is not available or ready when you invoke that operation.

Comment: In my application.yml I have the property:

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.lookupTable.consumer.materializedAs: lookupStore`

Do I need something more in the code?

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that. That should work. If you can share a small reproducible sample (with instructions to reproduce), I can take a peek at that.

Comment: My fault, I didn't mention before. I'll try to prepare a sample. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm getting closer to the problem. I have tried to query the lookupStore. If I use

```
final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<LookupKey, LookupData> lookupStore =
            interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore("myStore", QueryableStoreTypes.<LookupKey, LookupData>keyValueStore())
```

Then

```
lookupStore.get(key)
```

never returns a value. But if I create a HashMap like this:

```
final KeyValueIterator<LookupKey, LookupData> lookups = lookupStore.all();

Map<LookupKey, LookupData> lookupMap = new HashMap<>();
while (lookups.hasNext()) {
    KeyValue<LookupKey, LookupData> nextLookup = lookups.next();
    lookupMap.put(nextLookup.key, nextLookup.value);
}
lookups.close();
```

the hashMap contains the correct data and is returning the correct value to each key. But the GlobalKTable itself cannot be joined for some reason. It never gets any matches.

Comment: The the problem were somehow the avro-object keys. After changigng them to strings as well as correcting a namespace in a avro-schema the problem is solved.